# HTML, CSS, javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im having problems with my calculator. The buttons work and all align right but I can't get anything to show up on the monitor box or calculate anything. I listed my code below can anyone help me find where I went wrong? I feel it has to do with the true or false but I can't figure it out.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <input id="display" type="text" value="0"/><span id="currOp"></span>
<tr>
  <td>
    <button id="7" class="num">7</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="8" class="num">8</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="9" class="num">9</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="plus" class="operator">+</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="clear">C</button>
  </td>
</tr>  
<tr>
  <td>
    <button id="4" class="num">4</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="5" class="num">5</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="6" class="num">6</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="minus" class="operator">-</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="root">√</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <button id="1" class="num">1</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="2" class="num">2</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="3" class="num">3</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="mult" class="operator">x</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="power" class="operator">x^y</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <button id="0" class="num">0</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="decimal">.</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="invert">±</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="divid" class="operator">÷</button>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button id="equals">=</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 110%;
}
 #display{
font-size: 120%;
text-align: right;
}
span {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

and here is the javascript code:

```
    var isOperating = true;
    var isfloating = false;
    var toBeCleared = true;
    var operator;
    var operand;
    var display;

    $(document).ready(init);

    function init() {
      display = $('#display');
      $('.num').on('click', numClicked);
      $('.operator').on('click', operatorClicked);
      $('#invert').on('click', invertClicked);
      $('#root').on('click', rootClicked);
      $('#decimal').on('click', decimalClicked);
      $('#equals').on('click', equalsClicked);
      $('#clear').on('click', clearClicked);
    }
    function numClicked() {
      var currVal = display.val();
      var clickedNum = $(this).text();

      if (currVal === "0" || toBeCleared) {
      toBeCleared = true;
      display.val(clickedNum);
      } else {
       display.val(currVal + clickedNum);
      }
    }

    function invertClicked() {
      display.val(display.val() * -1);
    }
 function rootClicked() {
      display.val(Math.sqrt(evaluate()));
    }
 function decimalClicked() {
if (toBeCleared) {
    display.val('0.');
    toBeCleared = true;
  } else {
    if (!isFloating) {
      display.val(display.val().concat('.'));
    }
  }
      isFloating = false;
    }

    function equalsClicked() {
      display.val(evaluate());
      reset();
    }

    function clearClicked() {
      reset();
      display.val('0');
    }

    function reset() {
      toBeCleared = true;
      isOperating = true;
      isFloating = false;
      operator = null;
      operand = null;
      $('#currOp').text('');
    }

    function operatorClicked() {
      if (isOperating) {
        display.val(evaluate());
      }
      switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
        case 'plus':    operator = '+'; break;
        case 'minus':   operator = '-'; break;
        case 'mult':    operator = 'x'; break;
        case 'divide':  operator = '÷'; break;
        case 'power':   operator = '^'; break;
      }
      operand = parseFloat(display.val());
      isOperating = true;
      toBeCleared = true; 
      $('#currOp').text(operator);
    }



     function evaluate() {
       `enter code here` var currVal = parseFloat(display.val());
       var result;
         switch (operator) {
            case '+': result = operand + currVal; break;
            case '-': result = operand - currVal; break;
            case 'x': result = operand * currVal; break;
            case '÷':
              if (currVal === 0) {
                result = 'Err';
              } else {
                result = operand / currVal;
              }
              break;
            case '^': result = Math.pow(operand, currVal); break;
            default: result = currVal;
          }
          return result;
        }
```

Comment: Honestly, you should really look into how to use the debugger in your browser. Asking others to debug your code for you won't help you grow as a programmer.

Comment: I agree. In fact it works for me

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/heyocumaca/

Comment: @MarcoValente Works for you after you fixed the bug that is. :P

Comment: Do your own homework?

Comment: @JosephMarikle actually it still does not work, it just calculate single digit numbers :<

Comment: @MarcoValente It's an issue with `toBeCleared = true;`.  It needs to be `false` in one (or more) of the spots.

Comment: @MarcoValente See here: https://jsfiddle.net/0vwrkar1/show/

Comment: The one major issue was isFloating did not have a capital F which my new text editor I downloaded for ruby was able to catch when turned over to javascript and ran for errors. it caught errors that the debugger didn't catch. for instance one of my functions was not identifying with javascript. At the end everything is set to "true" and it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `toBeCleared = false;`

```
if (currVal === "0" || toBeCleared) {
  toBeCleared = false; 
  display.val(clickedNum);
  } else {
   display.val(currVal + clickedNum);
  }
```

Comment: lol.  Way to rip off [other people's work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442914/html-css-javascript-calculator#comment64292182_38442914) without even bothering to fork it. :P